# Inequality of the distance of points of a Euclidean space

Tags: linear-algebra, metric-spaces

If $ x, y, z, t \ in E $ a Euclidean space, show that:
$d(x,y)d(z,t) \leq d(x,z)d(y,t)+d(x,t)d(y,z)$
First study the case where $ t = 0 $, I can perform the test when the Euclidean space is the plane, since this is known by Ptolemy's theorem, but expanding a little to the distance terms has cost me a bit, I would like the suggestion to achieve the inequality. Thanks.

Comment: Choose three of points and orthogonally project the fourth into that plane to use Ptolemy's theorem. Then investigate what happens to the distances when you return the fourth point to its original position.

Answer (score 0):

The inequality is equivalent (by translating the vectors so that $t=0$) to $$\frac{|x-y|}{|x||y|}\le\frac{|x-z|}{|x||z|}+\frac{|y-z|}{|y||z|}$$

But in general $$\frac{|a-b|^2}{|a|^2|b|^2}=\frac{|a|^2-2a\cdot b+|b|^2}{|a|^2|b|^2}=\frac{1}{|b|^2}-2\frac{a}{|a|^2}\cdot\frac{b}{|b|^2}+\frac{1}{|a|^2}=\left|\frac{a}{|a|^2}-\frac{b}{|b|^2}\right|^2$$

Hence the required inequality is equivalent to $$\left|\frac{x}{|x|^2}-\frac{y}{|y|^2}\right|\le\left|\frac{x}{|x|^2}-\frac{z}{|z|^2}\right|+\left|\frac{y}{|y|^2}-\frac{z}{|z|^2}\right|$$ which is valid by the triangle inequality.

[To complete the proof, you need to consider the trivial cases when $x=0$ or $y=0$ or $z=0$.]